# Pandas Replace minimum values with a list of values - rowise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has numbers in all column's. I would like to find the minimum value of each column and replace them with a given set of values. I tried idxmin with iloc, but no luck , may be I'm using them in the wrong way. Any help is appreciated.

```
df = abs(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4)))
print (df)
print (df[df!=0].min(axis=0))
newvalues =[1,2,3,4]
```

Lets say the input is

```
          0         1         2         3
0  2.776975  1.433614  0.147925  0.032635
1  1.328099  0.050764  0.255676  0.360205
2  0.614594  0.547384  0.791848  0.340333
3  1.475486  0.114053  0.904416  0.060585
```

Expected Output would be

```
          0         1         2         3
0  2.776975  1.433614         3         4
1  1.328099         2  0.255676  0.360205
2         1  0.547384  0.791848  0.340333
3  1.475486  0.114053  0.904416  0.060585
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `mask`, `eq`, `mul`

```
df.mask(df.eq(df.min(0),1),df.eq(df.min(0),1).mul([1,2,3,4]))
Out[41]: 
          0         1         2         3
0  2.776975  1.433614  3.000000  4.000000
1  1.328099  2.000000  0.255676  0.360205
2  1.000000  0.547384  0.791848  0.340333
3  1.475486  0.114053  0.904416  0.060585
```

Or `np.putmask`

```
v=df.values
np.putmask(v, v==np.min(v,0), [1,2,3,4])
df
Out[72]: 
          0         1         2         3
0  2.776975  1.433614  3.000000  4.000000
1  1.328099  2.000000  0.255676  0.360205
2  1.000000  0.547384  0.791848  0.340333
3  1.475486  0.114053  0.904416  0.060585
```

Comment: Great answer--think you might be able to simplify with `df.idxmin(axis=0)`

Comment: Never knew about df.mask (). Thank you @wen

Comment: @BradSolomon Nice solution :-)

Comment: @Shijo Yw~ :-) Happy coding

Comment: I like this answer as well, inventive use of mask.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ find something new `np.putmask` :-)

Comment: Haha, quite nice. Too bad I can upvote just once. Will keep in mind for future reference.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ when I learn something new , I always want to share with your guys ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You could assign values to `df.values`, this should be really fast.

```
v = df.values
v[v.argmin(0), np.arange(len(v))] = newvalues
df[:] = v

df     
          0         1         2         3
0  2.776975  1.433614  3.000000  4.000000
1  1.328099  2.000000  0.255676  0.360205
2  1.000000  0.547384  0.791848  0.340333
3  1.475486  0.114053  0.904416  0.060585
```